# Computing percentage change between tables

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I'm a novice to SQL scripting. I am trying to figure out a design problem, involving some arithmetic computation.

I have two tables temp1 and temp2 with two columns
account no., ( Common in both tables )
balance ( float data type ).

1. I want to compare the balance columns in temp1 and temp2.
   print out the no. of accounts and percentage of match and mismatch.
2. output the a/c nos. whose balances don't match into a separate table..

Another question that I have is, how does sql handle the computation, if a value in a particular field is divided by 0?

Any help, will get me started.

Thanks

---

I tried the following :

```
SELECT T1.AcountNo, T1.Balance, T2.Balance, 
       T1.Balance/CASE T2.Balance WHEN 0 THEN NULL END) 
FROM Temp1 T1, Temp2 T2
WHERE 
  T1.AccountNo = T2.AccountNo
AND 
  ((T1.Balance / T2.Balance > 1.1) OR
   (T1.Balance / T2.Balance < 0.9))
```

But i'm still unable to circumvent the zero divisor problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT T1.AcountNo, T1.Balance, T2.Balance, 
       DECODE( NVL(T2.Balance, 0), 0, 0, T1.Balance, T2.Balance)
FROM Temp1 T1, Temp2 T2 
WHERE T1.AccountNo = T2.AccountNo 
  AND ((T1.Balance / T2.Balance > 1.1) OR (T1.Balance / T2.Balance < 0.9))
```

˙DECODE` function is defined like this:

```
decode( expression , search , result [, search , result]... [, default] )
```

So, in above code it works like this:

- NVL() - if T2.Balance is NULL convert it to 0
- if T2.Balance is 0, return 0
- else divide T1.Balance with T2.Balance

Answer (score 0):

For the first query I would use something like this, which prints the ratio of the two balances:

```
SELECT T1.AcountNo, T1.Balance, T2.Balance, T1.Balance / T2.Balance
FROM Temp1 T1, Temp2 T2
WHERE 
T1.AccountNo = T2.AccountNo
```

For the second query, I would use something like this, that returns all the accounts for which the different is more than 10%:

```
SELECT T1.AcountNo, T1.Balance, T2.Balance, T1.Balance / T2.Balance
FROM Temp1 T1, Temp2 T2
WHERE 
T1.AccountNo = T2.AccountNo
AND 
((T1.Balance / T2.Balance > 1.1)
OR
(T1.Balance / T2.Balance < 0.9))
```

Comment: Just wondering. Why not replace ((T1.Balance / T2.Balance > 1.1)
OR (T1.Balance / T2.Balance < 0.9)) as ((T1.Balance / T2.Balance) != 1) ?
Chances are there you might have accounts in between 1.1 and 0.9 ;)

Comment: @Guru - that's the whole idea of tolerance. If one table shows balance for account X to be 1000 and the other table shows 1000.1, is it a problem? May be, depending on your application. If the numbers have to be strict, you are correct, but if I understood the question correctly, he needs a tolerance. If 10% is too wide, he can use 1.0001 and 0.9999, no problem, it depends on the application.

Comment: Tolerance is fine. It took some time for me to understand it through, I thought != 1 is simple. BTW, I dint down vote. Simply I can't too. Cheers!